# iOS google maps sdk GMSMarker positioning

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am working with Google maps and I am able to center the map to the GMSMarker by using

```
 GMSCameraPosition *camera =
    [[GMSCameraPosition alloc] initWithTarget:marker.position
                                         zoom:MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL
                                      bearing:0
                                 viewingAngle:0];
    [mapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];
```

I am showing a custom callout of size 200*150 and part of it gets hidden when the camera position is changed but I want the callout to be in the center and the map point to be below it. Any ideas how to do this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have a look at using [GMSProjection](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_projection). To shift the center of the map 100px from the markers location you would do something like:

```
- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {
  CGPoint point = [mapView_.projection pointForCoordinate:marker.position];
  point.x = point.x + 100;
  GMSCameraUpdate *camera =
      [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:[mapView_.projection coordinateForPoint:point]];
  [mapView_ animateWithCameraUpdate:camera];
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but the map centers itself with the marker being the mid point.

Comment: Yes that is what the code that I wrote does. You need to modify point.x and point.y to be what ever offset you would like.

Comment: I added like 1000 to both x and y, same thing is happening.

Comment: Yeah, I have set it up properly and it is getting called too.

Comment: @skarE should i use this same method to center the selected marker in center? removing point.x

Comment: This has no effect for me.

Comment: Had the same issue. I was returning false and the end of this method, please check if you return true. Then the solution above works just fine!

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4, 3**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    var point:CGPoint = mapView.projection.point(for: marker.position)
    point.x = point.x + 100

    let camera:GMSCameraUpdate = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(mapView.projection.coordinate(for: point))
    mapView.animate(with: camera)

    return true
}
```