# when we clicked on my customized annotation pin, the custom calloutview not displayed in center of the view(iphone)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

[image]

when we click on customized annotation pin, the calloutview not displayed in center of the view,  rather showing half in the view and remaining out of the view. pls help me anybody. 
thanks in advance

```
    CGSize const kMultiRowCalloutCellSize = {300,140};

    - (id)initWithAnnotation:(id<MultiRowAnnotationProtocol>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier onCalloutAccessoryTapped:(MultiRowAccessoryTappedBlock)block {
    self = [super initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.contentHeight = 80.0;
        _yShadowOffset = 6;
        self.offsetFromParent = CGPointMake(78, -14); //this works for MKPinAnnotationView
        self.enabled = NO;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.cellInsetX = 15;
        self.cellOffsetY = 10;
        self.onCalloutAccessoryTapped = block;
        [self setTitleWithAnnotation:annotation];
        [self setCalloutCellsWithAnnotation:annotation];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: take a look at below Stackoverflow's answers: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/a/16706675/2695503 2) http://stackoverflow.com/a/16767124/2695503 might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
annotationView.centerOffset = CGPointMake( annotationView.centerOffset.x + annotationView.image.size.width/2, annotationView.centerOffset.y - annotationView.image.size.height/2 );
```

Add these lines in below mentioned delegate method.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
```